# How to combile the label and textfield in same line with littel bit space?

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application.In that i use the label and textfield in same line.Every label contain the different size of text.And i place the textfield after the completing the label width.But i want to place the textfield after completion of label text.For example in my view Server name: is the label ans naresh is the textfield.I got like Server name:space Naresh.But i want like Server name:Naresh.So please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resize your label according to its contents using this:

```
[label sizeToFit];
```

and then change the frame of your textField like this:

```
[textField setFrame:CGRectMake(label.frame.origin.x+label.frame.size.width, textField.frame.origin.y, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextFields leftView property. Here is a code snippet to do that.

```
- (void) addLeftViewToTextField:(UITextField*)textField {

    UILabel *leftView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 31)];
        leftView.text     = @"leftView";
    leftView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    textField.leftView = leftView;
    [leftView release];

}
```

use the method in your viewDidLoad like this

```
[self addLeftViewToTextField:yourTextFieldInstance];
```

Comment: this doesnt do what is being asked. It adds the label inside the textView